# Best Method to Spawn Process from SQL Server Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

How would I go about spawning a separate process using a SQL Server 05/08 trigger? Ideally, I would like to spawn the process and have SQL Server not wait on the process to finish execution. I need to pass a couple parameters from the insert that is triggering the process, but the executable would take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit of CLR Integration, combined with SQL Service Broker can help you here.

http://microsoft.apress.com/feature/70/asynchronous-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the system stored procedure xp_cmdshell

info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I saw that particular article, but didn't see an option to 'spawn and forget'. It seems like it waits for the output to be returned.

> xp_cmdshell operates synchronously. Control is not returned to the caller until the command-shell command is completed.

Comment: missed that important part of your question - oops!